# For aspnet docker images whats the difference between servercore tag and nanoserver tag?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, docker

Im deploying for the first time my company's application to a docker container. Se developed a .net 6 aplicatiom amd have been deploying it to their instance of IIS server for the past couple years.

We decided to attempt to move it to a docker container and I have been struggling since. First I tried using pure nanoserver image, than due to windows dependencies in the application moved up to windows image itself while installing .net sdk and vc_redist within the container. The image ended up with 15GB and the dotnet build time was very slow.

Some weeks later I discovered that aspnet image has tags with nanoserver and windowscore. Since the discovery, work was done to rebuilding a dockerfile using such images. The application sucessfully starts with each tag, but the nanoserver version crashes when loading a Db2 dll. This behavior does not happen with aspnet image tagged with servercore. Also, there was no need to install vc_redist. Ive attempted to copy some DLLs from vc_redist into nanoserver without success.

Why is this happening? Is there a way to copy necessary files into nanoserver?

The image im using is [this](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-dotnet-aspnet).

It would be great using the nanoserver tag as its size is around 700MB versus 4GB of the servercore tag.

Havent tried the runtime image yet - dont even know if its worth the attempt.

TLDR: Cant ship .net 6 app correctly to aspnet nanoserver image, but its working on aspnet servercore. Why is this happening? What can be done to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, the difference between Nano Server, Server Core, and the full Windows (Server) container image is just the set of files they provide. Nano Server is the smallest and can fulfill a lot of app scenarios but it is missing certain files that a specific app may require. For example, Nano Server doesn't have [security.dll](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-Containers/issues/134) but it does exist in Server Core. As you move up from Nano Server to Server Core to the full Windows image, you get increasingly more files/functionality.

The general approach to take is to use the smallest Windows base image that your app requires. Start with Nano Server and validate your app's functionality. If everything works, use that. If not, try Server Core. And if that still doesn't work, you're left with the full Windows image behemoth.